# Showing differential 1-form is well defined

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am studying analysis on manifolds, more specifically differential forms.
I have to show that form $\alpha = \cos(r)dz + r\sin(r)d\theta$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is well defined around the origin, where $(r, \theta, z)$ are cylindrical coordinates. I tried the following:
\begin{align}
\theta =& \arctan\Big(\frac{y}{x} \Big) \Rightarrow d\theta = -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} dx + \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} dy \\
r =& \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \Rightarrow dr = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dy \\
z =& z \qquad \quad\Rightarrow dz = dz
\end{align}
I inserted these into $\alpha$ I get:
\begin{align}
\alpha = \cos\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big) dz - \frac{y\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx + \frac{x\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dy  
\end{align}

Taking the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ I get $\alpha(0,0)$ = dz.
Is this ok? I does not look ok, because then I could just set $r = \theta = 0$ and get the same?

And a seperate question, to determen the ker($\alpha$) do I have to solve:
\begin{align}
cos(r)\frac{df}{dz} = 0 \\
r\sin(r)\frac{df}{d\theta} = 0
\end{align}

I am just having some trubles understanding general forms on manifolds, so I would be grateful for any tips or an explanation, not necessarily a solution.

Comment: Is it clear to you what the issue is with this form and what you have to verify?

Comment: Well I assume the problem is with definiton of $\theta$  since it is not continues at the origin so the form might not be neither

Comment: $\alpha(0,0)=dz$ looks correct to me simply because due to $\alpha=\cos r\,dz+r\sin r\,d\theta$ we don't need $\theta$ to define $\alpha$ in $r=0\,.$ Note that in polar or cylindrical coordinates many things are not well-defined at $r=0$ simply because $\theta$ is not defined there. That separate question should probably use partial derivatives and seems one about PDE. We don't need differential forms to solve that. If I am missing something: more context, more focus please.

Comment: That was my thinking for the first one. For the second one I have one more 1-form $\alpha_2 = dz + xdy$ and I have too show that distributions ker($\alpha$) and ker($\alpha_2$)are not involutive

Comment: I see only one differential form $\alpha\,.$ Not sure why you make your life harder by converting it to Cartesian coordinates. Presumably that's what you mean by "second one".

Comment: You forgot some square roots in your explicit formula. Note that $r\sin r \sim r^2$, and $r^2d\theta$ extends continuously across the origin.

Comment: @TedShifrin you are right, but it does not really change much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you've agreed that $r^2d\theta$ extends continuously across $r=0$ (i.e., the $z$-axis), even though $\theta$ is not well-defined at $r=0$.

To find $\ker\alpha$, you need to find at each point $(r,\theta,z)$ the (tangent) vectors $v$ so that $\alpha(v)=0$. If $v=a\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}+b\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+c\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$, this means we want all $(a,b,c)$ satisfying
$$(r\sin r)b + (\cos r)c = 0.$$
Away from $\cos r = 0$, this is given by the $2$-plane $c=-(r\tan r)b$ in $(a,b,c)$-space.

The interesting question (which I am guessing you're not ready to tackle yet) is whether the differential equation $\alpha = 0$ is *integrable*. That is, are there surfaces whose tangent plane at $p\in\Bbb R^3$ are precisely given by $\alpha(p)=0$? The necessary and sufficient condition for (local) integrability is given by the Frobenius condition
$$\alpha\wedge d\alpha = 0.$$
In this case, $\alpha\wedge d\alpha = (\sin r+\cos r(\sin r+r\cos r)) dr\wedge d\theta\wedge dz$, which is nonzero almost everywhere. Thus, this differential equation is not integrable.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and you are I write i have to show that distibution is not integrabile, which I did by calculating the commutator generting the distribution, however the provided condition is interesting

Comment: Ah, cool. So use the famous formula $d\alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y)) - Y(\alpha(X)) - \alpha([X,Y])$ to see that the two formulations are equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.